# Group calculations using group_by and subset commands

Tags: r, group-by, subset

I am a rookie STATA user trying to make the jump to R. I am working through various exercises, but keep getting something wrong with the group_by and subset command.

I have a simple dataset that I wish to make groupbased calculations on. I am trying to use the groups_by command from the dplyr package to do this.

My dataset is called itchy and consists of 4 variabels:
treat- levels A and B (type of treatment)
type- levels Dark and Fair (skin-colour)
y - levels 0 and 1 (failure or succes of treatment)
freq - numerical variable indicating how many are in this particular group

Using this code you can recreate it:

```
type <- c(2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1)
treat <-c(1,1,2,2,1,1,2,2)
y <- c(1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0)
freq <- c(9,17,5,20,10,15,3,20)
itchy <- cbind.data.frame(type,treat,y,freq)
itchy$type <- as.factor(type)
itchy$type <- factor(itchy$type,levels = c(1,2), labels = c("Dark", "Fair"))
itchy$treat <- as.factor(treat)
itchy$treat <- factor(itchy$treat,levels = c(1,2), labels = c("A", "B"))
itchy$y <- as.factor(y)
itchy$y <- factor(itchy$y,levels = c(0,1), labels = c("failure", "succes"))
```

Now I would like to calculate the ods for a success for treatment A and B when applied to skintype Dark or Fair. (ods = nr of successful events/nr of failures)

I have two questions:

1) Can you help me do the ods calculations by groups?
2) I have tried with various combinations of group_by and subset, without any luck. The below code shows some of my unsuccessful attempts. Can you then tell I have a basic misunderstanding of how the group_by and subset commands work

```
itchy %>% group_by(treat, type) %>% summarize(ods = (subset(freq, y==1)/subset(freq, y==0)))

itchy %>% group_by(treat, type) %>% ods <- c((subset(freq, y==1)/subset(freq, y==0)))

itchy %>% group_by(treat, type) %>% itchy$ods <- (subset(freq, y==1)/subset(freq, y==0))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, I think the following will work. I made use of the the spread function from the tidyr package, which like dplyr is part of the [tidyverse](https://www.tidyverse.org)

```r
library(tidyr)
itchy %>% 
  spread(y, freq) %>% 
  mutate(odds = succes / failure)

  type treat failure succes      odds
1 Dark     A      15     10 0.6666667
2 Dark     B      20      3 0.1500000
3 Fair     A      17      9 0.5294118
4 Fair     B      20      5 0.2500000
```

Comment: This worked like a charm.  
Just to make sure I understand the code: 
"spread" changes the y variable from long to wide format.
"mutate" generates a new variable

Comment: That is correct. I should have used the argument names for clarity. You can find the docs online at http://tidyr.tidyverse.org

Answer (score 1):

```
junk = itchy %>% group_by(y,treat, type) %>% summarize(Overall = sum(freq))
myfunc = function(arg1,arg2){
  filter(junk,treat == arg1,type == arg2)[1,4]/filter(junk,treat == arg1,type == arg2)[2,4]
}

myfunc("A","Dark") # You can try all the various combinations here
```

Does this give you the desired result?

Comment: No, I am sorry if my question wasnt clear enough:
 I want to compute: the ratio between succesfull and unsuccefull treatments
(ods = (subset(freq, y==1)/subset(freq, y==0)))
And I want to calculate this for the 4 groups;
Treat A + Type Fair
Treat A + Type Dark
Treat B + Type Fair
Treat B + Type Dark

Comment: @SteenHarsted I made some changes to the code. Can you check now?